# Overview of how to rewrite a URL for dynamically generated page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I am in the process of writing my own blog system as a practice exercise and I ran into a question that I'm having a hard time finding an answer for.

**What are the steps necessary to define and implement a custom URL for dynamically generated page?**

I'm really only looking for a high-level overview of the steps necessary.

### What I know:

I'd need to store this URL in my database, so I'll need to add a place for that to my model.

**PostModel.cs** (model)

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string IntroText { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

So, lets say I've successfully stored my desired URL in the database and it looks something like this:

```
/this-is-a-test-entry/
```

Currently I'm pulling my entries out based on their ID, but I'd like to be able to define my own URLs. I don't really know what the next step is from here. (Controller, route config, something else?)

Could someone provide a **high-level** overview of the next steps I need to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll have to do is start pulling out your records based on URL (make sure you index that property as well) then you can basically use the default route to do:

```
public class BlogController
{
    public ActionResult Post(string id)
    {
        //get the post via URL
    }
}
```

Then you can access that by navigating the following:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/Blog/Post/this-is-a-test-entry
```

Comment: This makes sense. So essentially when I have a url like "?id=3" I'm requesting that record by id... all I need to do instead is request it by my stored url?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Yeah basically, it's just your fetching mechanism that needs to change. If you haven't already as well make sure you have a unique constraint on your URL column.

Comment: wow, so simple. I look forward to trying this when I get home tonight. But I already know this answer is correct. Thanks mattommo!